# Greek/Roman play in which a woman encourages a pregnant slave to marry a slave owner and pass off the baby as his?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, literature, greece

I can’t for the life of me remember which play this is, or indeed whether it’s Greek or Roman? There’s presumably a lot more to the plot than this, but all I remember is that a young woman is sold into slavery while pregnant, and an older midwife figure who has been bribed by a foreman, encourages her to marry him and pretend the baby is his? Can anyone help?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might also try the [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/).